# Tenho uma classe simples e ela não atende quando chamo os métodos

Tags: python, classes, objetos, método

Alguém pode me ajudar?

```
class sorvete():
    def __init__(self,sabor, recipiente):
        self.sabor= sabor
        self.recipiente= recipiente
        self.ml= 0

    def sabor(self):
        print("O sabor que pediu é: ", (self.sabor))
        
    def recipiente(self):
        print("O recipiente que pediu é: ", (self.recipiente))
        

    def quantidade(self,ml):
        self.ml= self.ml + ml

sorvete1=sorvete('Morango','Casquinha')
print(sorvete1)
print(sorvete1.sabor())
print(sorvete1.recipiente())
print(sorvete1.quantidade(500))
```

Erro:

> TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

Comment: Você definiu um método com o mesmo nome de um atributo. Neste caso, quando vc chama `sorvete1.sabor()` o Python busca pelo atributo que é string. Mude o nome de um dos dois.

Comment: Acrescentando ao comentario do @PauloMarques, pode acessar os atributos desta forma `sorvete1.sabor` e `sorvete1.recipiente` [Veja mais aqui](https://cursos.alura.com.br/forum/topico-typeerror-str-object-is-not-callable-109559)

Comment: Deu certo !! Agradeço grandemente